# .htaccess, URL changes but loading content

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having an issue with .htaccess where I have managed to successfully rewrite the URLs but the content is no longer loading.

The following is my htaccess file.

I'm aiming for all my .html pages (the site is made of .html static pages) to have their extensions removed. However, I require the .html URLs to 301 redirect to the new URL's so that my SEO does not take a hit from these changes.

Example:

- Original: www.example.co.uk/page.html
- Desired: www.example.co.uk/page/

It is important that the original URL redirects the new URL's though.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# REDIRECT yourdomain.com TO www.yourdomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule (.+)\.html?$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*/)*[^/.]+)$ $1.html [L]
```

I have tried the htaccess above and I've also tried the variation below, but neither has worked as desired. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# REDIRECT yourdomain.com TO www.yourdomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule (.+)\.html?$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change 2 things.

1. Add this right after your redirect to prevent a redirect loop:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
   RewriteRule ^ - [L]
   ```
2. change the last rule to this:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1\.html -f
   RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L]
   ```